# HashMap - previous Key exists after insertion of new equal objects

Tags: java, collections

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.EqualsBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.HashCodeBuilder;

class Employee{
int id;

Employee(int id){
    this.id = id;
}
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Override
public int hashCode(){      
    return HashCodeBuilder.reflectionHashCode(this);
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj){      
    return EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(this, obj);   
}
}
public class P2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Employee emp1 = new Employee(10);
    Employee emp2 = new Employee(10);
    Employee emp3 = new Employee(14);        
    HashMap<Employee,String> emp = new HashMap();
    emp.put(emp1, "Employee1");
    emp.put(emp2, "Employee2");
    emp.put(emp3, "Employee3");     
    Set set = emp.keySet();
    Iterator it = set.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        Employee empl = (Employee)it.next();
        System.out.println(emp.get(empl));
    }
    System.out.println(emp.containsKey(emp1));      
    System.out.println(emp1.equals(emp2));
    System.out.println(emp.get(emp1));
}

}
```

Output :-

```
Employee2
Employee3
true
true
Employee2
```

here emp1 and emp2 are equal objects. 1st 2 output says we have 2 entry(not 3) in hashmap. Moment we insert second object(emp2) in hashmap it removes previous entry ie emp1. But 3rd output says hashmap still contains key emp1 and 5th output says key emp1 and emp2 refers same entry in hashmap. I am confused by this behavior of hashmap ie entry gone but key still exists and referring to next equal object.

Comment: hint your emp1 and emp2 both have same id (10) !

Comment: Nice input for a newbie ...

Answer (score 0):

Since both `emp1` and `emp2` have same `id` i.e. 10, `apache commons lib` is treating them as `equal` and `hashcode` is also the same. So when you put emp2 in hashmap, it actually doesn't add a new key to hashmap, it just replaces the existing value of "Employee1" to "Employee2". Since emp1 and emp2 are same, you will get true for both object when calling `contains()` method on hashmap. 
To avoid this:

1. Assign different ids to your employees
2. Add more properties to employee class
3. Let java itself decide the hashcode and equals instead of using Apache Commons Lib.

I may also add that instead of relying on reflection usage of HashCodeBuilder and EqualsBuilder you should use explicit fluent APIs that they provide.

Answer (score 0):

1. Basically, HashMap uses key.hashCode() and key.equals() to locate the value, so if two objects hashCode() method returns the same value, and equals() are also true, then they will consider the same key.
2. commons lang's reflectionHashCode() and reflectionEquals() are based on object's fields to generate the HashCode and Equals result. In your case, as there is only one field id for emp1 and emp2 and, they have the same value 10, so relfectionHashCode() will return the same value and reflectionEquals() will return true if compare the emp1 and emp2.

Based on above two points, emp1 and emp2 are actually the same key in HashMap's perspective. So emp.get(emp1) and emp.get(emp2) will return the same value, which is "Employee2".